# App crashes with Telegram Api in Node "Too much data to fetch"

Tags: node.js, crash, fetch, telegram, tdlib

here's the problem.
I've wrote an app with `tlg` module. [LINK GITHUB](https://github.com/dilongfa/node-tlg)

I've developed using Mac Os and everything worked fine but when i've tried to move all the app to a new Centos 8 VM, recompiling TDlib and launcing the app, here's the response after the app crash.

```
[ 0][t 4][1588032092.051109791][Status.h:191][!Td]  
Unexpexted Status [Error : 0 : Too much data to fetch at 8] in file 
/td/td/telegram/Global.cpp at line 77
```

This is weird, i've never seen an error like this. [Here's the Global.cpp](https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/master/td/telegram/Global.cpp)

Comment: I have the same problem and it's first time I see it. TDLib version is 1.6

Comment: I've recompiled the TDLib. The problem was that i used a wrong `libtdjson.so` downloaded from some website. https://tdlib.github.io/td/build.html - Here how to compile it with wizard. I've changed VM from CENTOS 8 to Ubuntu 18.04 and worked fine.

Comment: Nice to see it resolved. Thanks for the guide, I wasn't aware about it. Also an alternative way to make it is to compile it online using Appveyor. Required config and script is provided by [this](https://github.com/ForNeVeR/tdlib.native/) repository. But you may want use this scripts with your own (credible) TDLib fork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably used your app with a newer TDLib version and then came back to the old version, so the old td can't work with upgraded DB. So just stick with the new version.